# How to call "__call__()" method of python class from matlab

Tags: python, matlab

I'm working with a class like this:

```
class Select(object):       
    def __init__(self, interface):
        ...

    def project(self, ID):
        ...

    def __call__(self, datatype_or_path):
        ...
```

When I try to call this method (basically a functor) from Matlab like:

```
select = Select(blah);
select('blah');
```

I get the following error:

```
Array formation and parentheses-style indexing with objects of class
'py.pyxnat.core.select.Select' is not allowed.  Use objects of class
'py.pyxnat.core.select.Select' only as scalars or use a cell array.
```

**EDIT:**

`select.('__call__')('blah')` does not seem to work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Matlab Tech Support:

> My name is sai and I am writing in reference to your Technical Support
>   Case #01708094 regarding 'Calling python functors through matlab'.
>
> I understand that you are experiencing issues while invoking a functor
>   defined in python from MATLAB.
>
> I see that you are using MATLAB R2014b. Please note that **this is a
>   known issue in MATLAB R2014b which has been fixed in MATLAB R2015a and
>   there are no known work arounds for this issue in R2014b**. If it is
>   feasible, I would recommend to upgrade to MATLAB R2015a which will
>   help you resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the `Select` class you use in your code is a `py.pyxnat.core.select.Select`, not your own `Select` class. Check your imports (and specifically check for a 'star import' - `from xxx import *` - after the line where you import your own `Select` class.

Comment: No, I can call the other methods of `Select`. I just can't call the `__call__` method which acts like a functor in python. I cannot call it through matlab. Every other method I can call from matlab just fine. Hopefully this clears things up.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't really match the error message... Now I have near zero experience with matlab so I can only trust you - and then the solution is : rename your `Select` class to something that matlab doesn't confuse with it's own stuff.

Comment: It's a matlab error. There must be a problem with calling specialized methods like functors I guess.

Comment: Got a response from matlab tech support about this and posted an answer.